# Обновление NPM пакета в случае изменения README

Tags: npm, yarn

Насколько я понимаю, обновить свой NPM пакет можно только если была изменена его версия. Но что делать в тех случаях, когда я не хочу выпускать новую версию, но мне нужно, чтобы пакет обновился? Например, если я исправил ошибку в README файле, при этом ничего не исправив в коде. Можно ли как-нибудь обновить пакет в реестре, не обновляя при этом версию пакета (в т.ч. и на GitHub)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Крайне печально, но вот что по этому поводу говорит npmjs.org:

> The README displayed on the site will not be updated unless a new version of your package is published, so you would need to run npm version patch and npm publish to have a documentation fix displayed on the site.

По-русски (суть): для обновления README, отображаемого на сайте [npmjs.org] придется выпустить новую патч-версию.